# How can I remove orders from an order collection in Magento 2? Or how to generally remove items from any collection?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, collection

I'm using this code in a block to get a collection of orders in Magento 2:

```
$orders = $this->orderCollectionFactory->create()
            ->addFieldToSelect('*')
            ->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', $customerId);
```

And so far it works great, I can loop through the orders and output the order data in the frontend.

However, I want to remove some orders from this collection, for example order with ID of 21. I tried to use `removeItemByKey()` to accomplish this:

```
foreach ($orders as $order) {
    if($order->getId() == 21) $orders->removeItemByKey($order->getId());
}
```

But this doesn't work and the order with ID 21 remains in the order collection.

I've also tried this instead:

```
foreach ($orders as $order) {
    if($order->getId() == 21) unset($orders->{$order->getId()});
}
```

Same result, order 21 still in the collection.

Why doesn't this work and how can I remove stuff from the order collection?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the function itself,

```
    File: lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Data/Collection.php
    Line: 454-466
    /**
     * Remove item from collection by item key
     *
     * @param mixed $key
     * @return $this
     */
    public function removeItemByKey($key)
    {
        if (isset($this->_items[$key])) {
            unset($this->_items[$key]);
        }
        return $this;
    }
```

you can see that it removes by array key. My guess here is that the array key is not necessarily equal to `$order->getId()`.
You could rewrite your loop:

```
foreach ($orders as $key => $order) {
     if($order->getId() == 21) $orders->removeItemByKey($key);
 }
```

This should do the trick.

A more efficient way would be to pre filter your collection with `NOT IN` like:

```
$orderCollection->addFieldToFilter(
        'customer_id',
        $customerId
    )->addFieldToFilter(
        'order_id',
         array('nin' => $arrayWithOrderIds)
    );
```

Hope I could help.